# search and convert Uppercase to small case and inserting ''-'' in javascript

Tags: javascript

thanks in advance,
I have a string as "fileName = 'CampaignDetail'" .I want to make it 'campaign-detail'.That is converting all the upper case letters to small and insert hyphen wherever in between it is capital letter.how can I do it with for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this approach using `split` and `reduce`

```
"CampaignDetail".split(/(?:([A-Z]))/).reduce( (a,b,i) => i == 1 || i % 2 == 0 ? a + b : a + "-" + b ).toLowerCase() //campaign-detail
```

**Demo**

```js
function toHypenCase( input )
{
  return input.split(/(?:([A-Z]))/).reduce( (a,b,i) => i == 1 || i % 2 == 0 ? a + b : a + "-" + b ).toLowerCase();
}

console.log( toHypenCase( "CampaignDetail" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expression. Try following

```js
let regex = /[A-Z](\s\S)*[a-z]*/g;

let name = 'CampaignDetail';

let tempData = name.match(regex);

filename = tempData.reduce((a,b) => {
    return a.toLowerCase() + '-' + b.toLowerCase();
})

console.log(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Hope it helps

```js
var string = "CampaignDetail";
  
string = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2');
string = string.replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])/g, '$1-$2')
alert(string.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx only solution:

```
"CampaignDetailKebabCase".replace(/(.)([A-Z]{1})/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
```

Here we globally search for uppercase letter ([A-Z]) placed after any symbol (.) and replace this with the same any symbol '$1' , dash symbol '-' and the same upper case later '$2'.